# How to fake handwriting on pdf without printer and scanner?

Tags: pdf, digital-signature, digital-pen

Bureaucracy sometimes requires us to print a document,
fill in blank fields, sign it, scan it and send it back. 
Is there an easy way to fool the bureaucrats
when no printer or scanner are available? 
I already found lookslikescanned.com (dead link)
which allows you to make a PDF look liked scanned,
but I still haven't figured out yet a way
to generate fake handwriting on a PDF document
as if it had been written with a pen on actual paper.

<sup>Historical note: [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20210217220754/http://lookslikescanned.com/) is what lookslikescanned.com looked like
when it existed, courtesy of the Wayback Machine.</sup>

Comment: This is the first time I hear of such a requirement. Have you tried filling in the PDF using a handwritten font and then making it look like scanned?

Comment: you can check answers [there](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/94523/51224).

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what your bureaucrats are looking for specifically, but you could just:

1. take a picture of your writing/signature written on real paper with a real pen
2. use an editor (PDF or image editor like [gimp](https://www.gimp.org/)) to add your small written images onto the PDF

Comment: If I need to fill in many fields (not just signature), I guess I would have to write on paper all the text, take many pictures and treat them as many "signatures"?

Comment: Basically yes. But I'd imagine the signature would be the most important part that needs writing, almost everything else could be "typed" (with a fillable PDF or adding text), couldn't it?

Comment: Good point, I should try that. The instructions said explicitly to print, write and scan, so I just assumed the bureaucrats at the other end were expecting everything handwritten, but maybe they can tolerate some typing as long as the signature is handwritten, I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

There is an [online tool to make a pdf look scanned](https://supertool.org/make-a-pdf-look-printed-and-scanned/) and it has the ability to insert signatures that look handwritten:

https://supertool.org/make-a-pdf-look-printed-and-scanned/